# Creating tooltip on form label with content from a different model in django-admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have two models: `PrimaryEntity` and `SecondaryEntity`. When i render the form based on `PrimaryEntity`, i wish to have a tool tip on certain Form Labels that show data from specific columns in `SecondaryEntity`.

Here is the model example:

```
class PrimaryEntity(models.Model):
    some_field1 = models.TextField(default=None, blank=False, null=True)
    some_field2 = models.CharField(default=None, max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    some_field3 = models.CharField(default=None, max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    some_field4 = models.CharField(default=None, max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class SecondaryEntity(models.Model):
    field1 = models.TextField(default=None, blank=False, null=True)
    field2 = models.CharField(default=None, max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    field3 = models.CharField(default=None, max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    field4 = models.CharField(default=None, max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

So when i render my `change_form.html` based on `PrimaryEntity`, i would like to enable the label for `PrimaryEntity.some_field1` to render data from `SecondaryEntity.field1` in e.g. a tooltip.

So the question is:

- How do i include 2 models in one `ModelAdmin` and how do i manipulate the labels with the data?

Should i stick to using the django admin platform or is this type of task best served as a custom admin page?

**UPDATE:**

Alternatively making a side-by-side field would get the job done aswell, instead of the tooltip method.

In other words:

```
 ______________________________ ______________________________
|                              |                              |
|                              |                              |
|    SecondaryEntity.field1    |  PrimaryEntity.some_field1   |
|                              |                              |
|______________________________|______________________________|
```

Where `SecondaryEntity.field1` would be read-only in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that there is no relationship between your two Models. There should be a OneToOneField or ForeigkKey Field in the PrimaryEntity. Following a short version of how it could look.

```html
class PrimaryEntity(models.Model):
    some_field1 = models.TextField(default=None, blank=False, null=True)

class SecondaryEntity(models.Model):
    field1 = models.TextField(default=None, blank=False, null=True)
    primary_entity = models.OneToOneField(PrimaryEntity)
    @property
    def some_field1(self):
        return self.primary_entity.some_field1
```

The property you can then show in the admin. Just add it to list_display.